# Win32 Api to convert 2-letter (neutral) identifiers to Language

Tags: c++, windows, locale

I need to convert some 2-letter (neutral) identifiers (like `en` for English) so something more friendly for user, like English.

Is there an Api that does that using Win32 ? So far I have found only [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) family of functions that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `IsValidLocaleName`, `GetLocaleInfoEx` and `LOCALE_SLANGUAGE` / `LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDLANGUAGENAME` / `LOCALE_SENGLISHLANGUAGENAME`, which are defined in `WinNls.h` as:

```cpp
#define LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME  0x00000002   // localized name of locale, eg "German (Germany)" in UI language
#if (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA)
#define LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDLANGUAGENAME 0x0000006f   // Language Display Name for a language, eg "German" in UI language
#endif //(WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA)
#define LOCALE_SENGLISHLANGUAGENAME   0x00001001   // English name of language, eg "German"
#define LOCALE_SNATIVELANGUAGENAME    0x00000004   // native name of language, eg "Deutsch"
```

(depending on OS version and your requirements).

Note: XP only uses `LCID`'s

Answer (score 1):

here is a table : 
http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm
copy paste it, put it into a map and there you go.

Comment: thanks but mapping should be my last option. Must be some Api that already does that. And second: there may be some (minor) differences: like: traditional Chinese (zh-Hant) and simplified Chinese (zh-Hans) vs zh-CN, zh-HK, zh-MO ...